# Setting "ActionController::Parameters.permit_all_parameters = true" in initializer not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails project I want to set

```
ActionController::Parameters.permit_all_parameters = true
```

so,

1. I created the file config/initializers/permit_all_params.rb
2. I put this line of code in the config/initializers/permit_all_params.rb
3. Then I restarted the rails console, print ActionController::Parameters.permit_all_parameters

the value still shows "false". reload and restart the rails project won't fix this.

Anyone knows why this initializer file doesn't work and how could I make this work?

thank you!

Comment: When do you get that error? When the application starts or when you do a request? What request? What does the controller look like? Btw. there is no Ruby 6. Did you update from Rails 3 to Rails 6? In one step or in smaller steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This option is loaded when action controller is loaded:
*https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.1.7.2/actionpack/lib/action_controller/railtie.rb#L28*

```rb
ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller, run_once: true) do
  ActionController::Parameters.permit_all_parameters = options.delete(:permit_all_parameters) { false }
...
```

Official way of setting this option is through config:
*https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#config-action-controller-permit-all-parameters*

```rb
# config/initializers/permit_all_params.rb
Rails.configuration.action_controller.permit_all_parameters = true
```

In a console you need to load `ActionController::Base` to execute `on_load` hook:
*https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.1.7.2/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb#L271*

```rb
>> ActionController::Parameters.permit_all_parameters
=> false
# load action controller
>> ActionController::Base
=> ActionController::Base
>> ActionController::Parameters.permit_all_parameters
=> true
```